# How to move Right aside div above Left content div

Tags: css, responsive-design, resize

I have two divs, a main left content and a right aside. With a media query (as screen gets smaller), I want the left content div to move down and allow the right aside div to move above it.

Here's what I currently have...

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="content">content</div>
    <div id="aside">aside</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    #content {
    color:white;
    width:70%;
    background: #111; height: 100px;
    position:inline;
    float:left;}

    #aside { 
    float: right; 
    background: #CCC; height: 100px;width: 100px;}

    @media screen and (max-width: 500px){
    #content {
    width: 100%; 
    margin-left: 0px;
    clear: both;
    }}
```

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/kaveman71/n55444ca/1/

At present, when resized smaller, the aside div moves below the content div (per usual), but I want the opposite to happen; the aside div should move above the (not literally on top of) left content div.

So when resized smaller, the results should be the gray aside box pops up **above** the black content box.

Is there a way to do this with CSS? Or do I need to resort to JavaScript? If JS is the only way, can anyone provide an example?

Thanks,

k

Comment: Thanks so much @Héctor E & Alex Wright!

Alex, if you'd gotten in a minute sooner than Hector, I could have marked yours as correct, but as it is, Hector's suggestion was sufficient for attaining the desired result.

Thanks so much guys!

Comment: note: `position: inline` doesn't exist: you're mixing `display: inline|inline-block|many other possible values` and `position: relative|absolute|static|fixed`

Comment: If HTML order must be kept (because nobody will let you change it or because it makes no semantical sense to have aside before main content), other solutions are [CSS flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and a bit hackish `display: table-caption` on second element (resp. IE10+ and IE8+)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you invert the order of the divs, as their position when fullscreen is defined by the css, it should place the aside over the content on resizing.

```
<div id="aside">aside</div>
<div id="content">content</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first that comes to mind is to put the aside first in the HTML content order.

```
<div id="aside"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

By default, the aside will be on top of the content div.

Then, with a media query, you can put the content to the left of the aside, using something like:

```
@media (min-width: 500px) {
    #content {
        float: left;
        width: 70%;
    }
    #aside {
        float: right;
        width: 100px
    }

}
```